# ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

On my ubuntu 18.04 host machine
I ran `sdkmanager`. After the update today
the emulator does not work anymore.

The error output:

```
sandbox@sanbox-host:~/.android$ emulator/./emulator -avd bykea1 -verbose
emulator: Android emulator version 27.3.10.0 (build_id 4969155) (CL:751f3c993c814a52adf144c159615ce457c2d282)
emulator: Found AVD name 'bykea1'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator/./emulator'; program directory: '/home/sandbox/.android/emulator'
emulator: Cannot find system image path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
emulator: Auto-config: -engine classic (based on configuration)
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
sandbox@sanbox-host:~/.android$ export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/sandbox/.android/
sandbox@sanbox-host:~/.android$ emulator/./emulator -avd bykea1 -verbose
emulator: Android emulator version 27.3.10.0 (build_id 4969155) (CL:751f3c993c814a52adf144c159615ce457c2d282)
emulator: Found AVD name 'bykea1'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator/./emulator'; program directory: '/home/sandbox/.android/emulator'
emulator: Cannot find system image path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
emulator: Auto-config: -engine classic (based on configuration)
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/sandbox/.android/]!
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, have you found a solution?